# RestEasy : GET request with multiple dynamic arguments

Tags: web-services, rest, resteasy

The required URL should be something like this :

`http://<host>:<port>/path/item?<arguments>`

The arguments key and value supposed to be multiple and dynamic, so I cannot use `@BeanParam` or `@QueryParam`. Also I can only call this interface without implementation.

My current code is something like this :

```
public interface RestService {

    @GET
    @Path("/path/item")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public JsonNode method(@QueryParam("params") String params);
}
```

Example of arguments that I want to pass : brand=myBrand&price=myPrice

Is there any way to do something like this ?

My References :

1. [REST Web Service - Dynamic Query Parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12513307/rest-web-service-dynamic-query-parameters)
2. [Passing indefinite Query Parameters with RESTful URL and reading them in RESTEasy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10735064/passing-indefinite-query-parameters-with-restful-url-and-reading-them-in-resteas)

Answer (score 1):

Use [`UriInfo.getQueryParameters()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/core/UriInfo.html#getQueryParameters--), as following:

```java
@GET
@Path("/path/item")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public JsonNode method(@Context UriInfo uriInfo) {
    MultivaluedMap<String, String> queryParams = uriInfo.getQueryParameters(); 
    ...
}
```

It returns a [`MultivaluedMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/core/MultivaluedMap.html). Then just iterate over it.

Comment: Thanks but currently I can only use interface. Is it possible to pass `Map` that contain each parameter name/value? But anyway I didn't use this method anymore. Seems like I cant send dynamic parameters.